# What is this insect (or spider)?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Location: Vienna, Austria

Date: July 18th

Daytime: around 5pm

Begaviours: none, unfortunately. Just walking

I take these to be six legs and some kind of appendices. But I am not entirely sure.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a [true bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera) larvae - thus, an insect - you correctly counted six legs :)
Characteristics of true bug larvae are the combination of the rostrum, the wing pockets and the dorsal scent glands (although the latter both are hard to see on the photos).

I suspect the specimen to be a member of the family Coreidae as it exhibits typical (larval) characteristics of this family: a rhomb shaped body and long legs and antenna. Also spines are a common feature of this family.

Although a bit hard to tell from the photos, I find it to be most similar to [*Coreus marginatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreus_marginatus), a common species in Central Europe.
Comparing two of the specimen's photos with those showing *C. marginatus* from a similar perspective, shows that - besides the general habitus and coloration - the number and position of the dorsal spines (2 x 2 central and 2 x 3 lateral) match well.
Also, the antenna are relatively large in comparison to the body ([compare also this photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Coreus_marginatus-n.jpg)).

In comparison, a *Leptoglossus occidentalis* larvae (as this species was suggested in [another answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/112744/39466)) would have a generally more elongated habitus with thinner antennae. And, most strikingly, *L. occidentalis* larvae have a more-than-body-long rostrum.

For comparison, here are more photos of...

- [European Coreidae here](https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/gallery/heteroptera/Coreidae/coreidae.html) or [here](http://heteroptera.eu/)
- [*C. marginatus* larvae](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Coreus_marginatus_(nymph))
- [*L. occidentalis* larvae](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Leptoglossus_occidentalis_(nymph))

[image: Specimen vs Coreus marginatus larvae vs Leptoglossus occidentalis larvae]

---

Image source (in reading direction):
[B. Schoenmakers CC-BY-3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Coreus_marginatus_%28Coreidae%29_-_%28nymph%29,_Arnhem,_the_Netherlands.jpg) |
[B. Schoenmakers CC-BY-3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Coreus_marginatus_(Coreidae)_-_(nymph),_Arnhem,_the_Netherlands_-_2.jpg) |
[B. Schoenmakers CC-BY-3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Leptoglossus_occidentalis_(Coreidae)_-_(nymph),_San_Vito_Lo_Capo_(comuni),_Italy.jpg) |
[Slimguy CC-BY-4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2019_07_01_Leptoglossus_occidentalis.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be [this animal](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1999752/bgimage). It is the nymph of *Leptoglossus occidentalis*, the Western Conifer Seed Bug.

It fits in terms of size and the greenish-brown colour of the abdomen. Also the position of the spikes and the long antennae are a match, eventhough the antenna look a bit more flat and broad in your picture and less hairy.

This invasive species is originally from the US. It was first recorded in Vienna in [2006](http://objekte.nhm-wien.ac.at/objekt/th1649/ob227).